# In Washington, does a homeowner with no HOA need any permits to self-install a mini-split AC?

Tags: air-conditioning

My buddy lives in a Single Family Home in King County, WA. We're in the middle of the biggest heatwave in a century so I've suggested we drive to Home Depot, pickup a mini split and self-install it over a weekend. Since his house is in his full ownership with no HOA, it doesn't seem like there's a legal barrier to just doing it on your own. But perhaps I'm missing something and you need some sort of a permit?

I do know electrical work requires a permit but there's already a high voltage outlet in the room where we'd install the AC so no wiring will be changed.

Comment: Think I would be more worried if you can find any ACs.  Permits usually depend on what local gov says, but usually simple plug ins don't need one.  Call up locals and see.

Comment: @crip659 Home Depot does have mini splits available, as far as I can tell, though there's some wait time for delivery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to it.

### The building permit

That's a local affair.  You need to talk to the AHJ about the building permit and the requisite inspections.  This includes electrical, since it will be a hardwired unit with a disconnect, and will also require a nearby 120V outlet be installed.   Electrical generally requires this even though we talk fast and loose about it here.

**The permit and inspection process *has nothing to do with* "hiring a professional"**.  They are orthogonal.  A DIYer can pull a permit.  A contractor might not.

Of course, *lots of people* incorrectly equate the two, and say "hiring the work done is so expensive that I think I'll just ignore the permitting process; even if they catch up with me, the fine *can't* be more than hiring a pro."  Naturally, cities had to find a way to counter this.  Their answer is that the penalty is that you must demolish the illegal work (and pull a permit to demolish it)... and if doing so leaves your house not legal for occupancy, pull *another* permit to raise the house to a fit state.  And since that involves freon drawdown, see below.

### The freon handling

This is a Federal requirement, though it may have local implementations.  See 40 CFR 82.150 *et.seq.* and the meat is at [82.154](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=sp40.21.82.f&rgn=div6#se40.21.82_1154).

Just because R-410A is *less destructive* than R-22 does not mean you get to "roll coal". There are controls on most refrigerants, and so you need to be licensed and have the necessary equipment and supplier relationships to achieve the recycling or annihilation of the freon.

However, this requirement is bypassed when using certain mini-splits which are *pre-charged* and UL-listed for DIY installation.  These have begun to appear on the market.  They have fittings able to snap together hermetically, preventing freon from escaping.

The requirement comes back into play when disassembling/demolishng that installation, so yeah, when the inspector catches you and makes you tear it out, you will need to hire a pro for that.

Comment: The freon requirement is the Kyoto Protocol. Those old A/Cs are generally costing their replacement price every couple of years in poor efficiency, but somebody else pays the electric bill, eh?  *This conversation has been brought to you by the word "externality"...*

Answer (score 1):

https://kingcounty.gov/depts/local-services/permits/permits-inspections/do-you-need-a-permit.aspx

Yes:

```
You need a mechanical permit to install, enlarge, move, or replace mechanical equipment.

Examples:

Installing a new fireplace or wood-burning stove
Installing a new furnace, air conditioner, or heat pump
```

In general, installing a heat pump (even a mini-split) wrong can release nasty chemicals into the atmosphere, so there's a legitimate concern over making sure it's done properly.

The penalty for not getting a permit is a maximum of $1000 per week, or jail time. (I'll note that getting a permit is something a homeowner can do; you don't really need a professional to manage this.)
https://kingcounty.gov/council/legislation/kc_code/32_Title_23.aspx

Comment: You must be thinking of R22 which causes ozone depletion and thus indeed nasty. The newer R410A is much safer.

Comment: Could you also specify the penalty for installing without a permit? Can't seem to find it on that page. Might still be cheaper than paying someone - he's previously been quoted $5k for the job so anything less than that is still better.

Comment: @JonathanReez It's not ozone-depleting, but it's a really potent greenhouse gas, so it's still nasty, just in a different way. 1 kg of R410a is equivalent to more than two metric tons of CO₂.